# Winsock listen and accept functions (C++)

Tags: c++, winsock, listen

If I have a listening socket in an infinite loop, is there any way for me to know whether a connection has been established with it before I run the accept function?
I want to be able to perform some actions before I do:

```
sock_connection[0] = accept(sock_listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Address, &AddressSize)
```

Specifically, as you can see my sock_connection[0] variable is an array. Now, before I actually accept a connection, I want to be able to traverse this array and instead of the 0 that it has now, it should return an available spot in the array.

So, is there any way to detect a connection prior to running accept?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be easier to use a dynamic container?

Something like:

```
vector<int> socket_pool;
int connection = accept(sock_listen, (SOCKADDR*)&Address, &AddressSize);

if (connection > 0)
     socket_pool.push_back(connection);
```

Comment: You will not be able to service the io events at those sockets if the thread is blocked in a select call.

Comment: @infact I haven't tried this with blocking sockets, however I use this strategy in a non blocking socket server and works fine. Thanks for the comment.